# Display is darkened off batteries and bright when on them

Tags: windows-7, display

I know the settings for power saving. The display gets dark when on batteries and it was the same few days ago.

Now it is reversed, dark when off batteries and bright when on them! I don't know what to do about it at all. Dell VOSTRO-1015 win-7-home-basic

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Your question is badly written and can be a bit difficult to understand. If you rewrite your question to include the problem using other sentences and what you have done so far to resolve the problem, your chances of getting a good answer will increase.

Comment: So, have you checked the settings in power saving to see how they are set NOW? You might also want to make sure that MSE is up to date and run a full scan - when mysterious things happen, eliminate "I'm infected" first...